# Setting Metadata in Word and Retrieving in Excel

Tags: vba, ms-word, metadata, excel-2016, word-2016

I'm trying to write a program that updates a Word document's metadata with content control boxes. The Excel document then loops through a directory that holds these documents and catalogs them by the metadata. In Word, I can set built-in properties in the DocumentBeforeSave sub via...

```
Application.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value = _
Application.ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Tags").Item(1).Range.Text
```

and retrieve those in Excel via the shell...

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(WB.Path & "\QA\")

For Each strFileName In objFolder.Items
     inputStr = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 18) 'Tags
     '...
     '...

next strFileName
```

The problem is that there are indexes in the "GetDetailsOf" function that I want to use but can't figure out how to set in Word. For example, I'd like to set the Division (GetDetailsOf index 155), Group (172), Program (277), and Attachments (219) fields. How do you set properties such as these that are not built-in?

Comment: You can use custom document properties.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the pointer. I think this should work for me.